# Why does force close occurs when moving from one Fragment to another Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to move from one fragment i.e mycontacts extends Fragment to another fragment friendfragment extends Fragment on a click of a button. I get the error like `No View found for Fragment`. My codes and error logs are as below. Kindly guide me as I am a newbie to Fragments.

tasks.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/tasky"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >


  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.taskmanager.friendfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Button" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

mycontacts.class

```
        Fragment fr;
      fr=new friendfragment();
      FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
      android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
      ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);

               ft.commit();
```

friendfragment.class

```
 public class friendfragment extends Fragment {
public friendfragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks, container,
            false);
    return view;
}
}
```

tasks.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tasky"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.taskmanager.friendfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button" />
```

some of the error logs

```
04-23 15:00:21.074: E/Trace(26708): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 15:00:47.933: E/FragmentManager(26708): No view found for id 0x7f040051 (com.example.taskmanager:id/fragment1) for fragment friendfragment{40e187b8 #1 id=0x7f040051}
04-23 15:00:47.933: E/FragmentManager(26708): Activity state:
04-23 15:00:47.963: E/FragmentManager(26708):   Local Activity 40cd4eb8 State:
04-23 15:00:47.973: E/FragmentManager(26708):     mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
04-23 15:00:47.995: E/FragmentManager(26708):     mLoadersStarted=true
04-23 15:00:47.995: E/FragmentManager(26708):     mChangingConfigurations=false
04-23 15:00:48.003: E/FragmentManager(26708):     mCurrentConfig={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h455dp 160dpi nrml port finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h s.6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tasks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/frame_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

 </FrameLayout>
```

fragment_friend.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativewLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

     <!-- Your views here -->

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment class:

```
   public class friendfragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friend, container,
                false);
        return view;
    }
   }
```

FragmentActivty:

```
 Fragment fr = new friendfragment();
 FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fr).commit();
```